# CSS Images disappear on refresh

Tags: image, css, coda

I'm applying an image to a `li` element in CSS, the image appears next to the `li` items when I first load but then after a refresh they vanish and are replaced by bullet point. I'm using the preview option coda 2 which uses Safari but in Firefox (latest version) and Chrome (latest) the images don't even load.

My CSS code is really simple and I have no idea why this issue is taking place

```
ul {
    list-style-image:url("images/star.png");
}  

li {
    margin: 10px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: check the console to see if you get any errors (F12 in Chrome and FF)

Answer (score 1):

Your CSS should be working. Test:

```css
ul {
  list-style-image: url(http://stater.mahdaen.name/icons/favicon-16x16.png);
}
li {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
```

```html
<ul class="org">
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
  <li>Test</li>
</ul>
```

If your CSS is not working, then you may check this:

1. Do not apply custom display to the `li` (e.g `inline-block`).
2. Image is exist.
3. List style is still not overridden by other css.

Comment: Hi, the above code doens't work, strangely if i embed the css code into my html document then it works fine but from a seperate css file then issues arise.

Comment: Can you show me your directory structure? Probably your css file is not in the same folder of the image, and you need to change `url(images/...);` to match to your directory structure. E.g: `url(../images/...);`