# Randomly (dis)appearing SVG bullet points

Tags: html, css, image, firefox, svg

While trying to add some nice SVG images as bullet points for my site, I came across some real strange behaviour and what appears to be a bug in Firefox. I've debugged it to the following MWE:

#### Source code

I have the following HTML document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
        ul {
            list-style-image: url('listImage.svg');
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

I also have the following SVG file called `listImage.svg`:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="4" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

#### The problem

When I open the HTML document in Firefox, the list appears as it should, with the SVG nicely appearing as the bullet point of the list:

[image: The unordered list, with the svg-images nicely in front of the list's items]

But when I refresh the page or reload the page, they sometimes disappear:

[image: The same unordered list, but without the svg-images in front of the items]

While refreshing the page, the images seemingly random keep appearing and disappearing again. Doing a hard refresh instead (with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>) or deleting the cache and offline website data doesn't change this.

#### Specific browsers

This problem is only happening in Firefox

```
Firefox Quantum 65.0 (64-bits)
Firefox Developer Edition 66.0b4 (64-bits)
```

In other browsers I did not have any problems, the images always appeared.

```
Internet Explorer 11
    Version: 11.523.17134.0
    Updateversions: 11.0.105 (KB4480965)
Edge
    42.17134.1.0
    Microsoft EdgeHTML 17.17134
```

(If someone could provide information about Google Chrome, please edit and add it to the question. I used some online tool and the results of that suggest that the SVG appears fine in Google Chrome, however I don't think this test is solid proof for it)

### Why is this happening?

**Related questions**

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32596026/8527611) that might be related, however this question is different since I'm only having this issue in Firefox and the answer(s) to that question have not solved my problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L41a3fdc/ works in chrome(Version 71.0.3578.98 (Official Build) (64-bit)), FF Dev Ed 66.0b2 BUT actually in FF QUANTUM 64.0.2 (64-bit), if you click RUN, the bullets disappear....

Comment: gifs behave as expected: https://jsfiddle.net/k27L6yr5

Comment: I digged in a bit deeper and found out: your svg-image has neither width nor height defined, doing so resolves the problem, see updated answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot answer on the behavior in `FF Dev Ed 66.0b2` but there is a work around to get the pretended result looking nice in FF and Chrome (not tested with Edge or Safari):

use the svg background image in your li tag instead of the ul list-style-image. Set this background's position and add a padding to the li

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-left: -20px;
}

li {
  background-image: url('https://dev.w3.org/SVG/tools/svgweb/samples/svg-files/410.svg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 0px 6px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  background-size: 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
</ul>
```

this is the corresponding [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2jLaptey/)

**edit:** as I wrote in my comment, *.gif files behave as expected in FF and Chrome, check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/k27L6yr5). Therefore an alternative answer would be:

keep your code, just convert the svg into gif

**UPDATE:** your svg-image has neither width nor height defined, doing so resolves the problem:

```
<svg width="15" height="15" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <circle cx="0" cy="0" r="4" />
    </g>
</svg>
```

check: https://jsfiddle.net/zf1hjrav/

Comment: Ah. Good to know that it is because of the missing height and width attributes. The reason this happend is because I started with some SVG generated by Adobe Illustrator and kept removing unncecassry code till I got the barebone that gave no errors. I used that to make the SVG from code myself.